# AWS QuickSight dashboard with multiple datasets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

Is it possible to create single AWS QuickSight dashboard containing analysis from different datasets?

What I have seen that one can create an analysis on a single dataset, can add multiple charts for the same one and it gets published as a dashboard.

Is it possible that we have one chart from dataset1 and another chart from dataset2 and both of them are part of a single analysis/dashboard?

Answer (score 11):

Yes it is possible, charts are called visuals on an analysis and the steps to create a visual from a completely separate dataset to the others is as easy as the following.

Click on the pencil icon in the dataset section
[image: Click the pencil icon in the dataset section]

Click Add dataset
[image: Click Add dataset]

Select the dataset you want to make the new visual from
[image: Select the dataset you want to make the new visual from]

Make sure the dataset you want to use is selected in the drop-down in the dataset section (1) and click the add button in the top left corner (2)
[image: Make sure the dataset you wish to use is selected in the drop-down and click Add in the top left corner]

Click Add visual and create your visual as you would normally

[image: Click Add visual]

Now you have two visuals from distinct datasets in one analysis, this can be published and both visuals will be on the same dashboard
[image: Two visuals from distinct datasets]